# Qt or C++ checking for NULL condition

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am writing an application with a submit button but I want to check if the textfield has been filled if not do not submit.

Not quite sure how the code should go.

My code currently looks like

```
if(flightNumber == NULL)
{
   flightNumbertext.text.color = 'red';
}
```

I am designing this for a Qt Quick application written in QML.

Comment: Check the docs for the widget you're using for `flightNumber`. If it's a QLineEdit, for example, check its [text()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlineedit.html#text-prop) property.

Comment: hi please is there anyway I can check the input in an email field fulfills the conditions for being a valid email address.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778390/check-if-email-are-valid-and-exists

Comment: I managed to edit the code and the following does work                                (flightNumber.text.length == 0)                                              but leaves a loop hole in that it allows white spaces to be considered as values.                                                                       Trying to use the isEmpty or iNull so far results in an error telling me flightNumber isn't a function which I kind of agree with but just can't figure out my way around this since using QTQuick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of playing, I think this will work for you

```
if (flightNumber.text.trim().length == 0) {
    flightNumbertext.text.color = 'red'; 
}
```

The function trim() is like QString::trimmed().  It removes both leading and trailing spaces from the `string`.

Answer (score 4):

QT's editing widgets use [QString](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html).

QString has many methods that you can use.

Use [isEmpty](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#isEmpty) or [isNull](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#isNull) methods of QString.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I managed to edit the code and the following does work                                (flightNumber.text.length == 0)                                              but leaves a loop hole in that it allows white spaces to be considered as values.                                                                       Trying to use the isEmpty or iNull so far results in an error telling me flightNumber isn't a function which I kind of agree with but just can't figure out my way around this since using QTQuick