# Verify that a user's email exists in provided domain using PHP

Tags: php, email, email-verification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [check if email are valid and exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778390/check-if-email-are-valid-and-exists)
>   [How to validate an email address in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026842/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-php)

I am developing a application for sending mail by provided mail address in PHP. now i wanna validate given mail address is really exist in domain or not

```
  **i.e
    abc@xyz.com (for example its registred in xyz domain)
    abcd@xyz.com (for example its nod registred xyz domain)**
```

how can i verify it by using PHP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you going to have a list of emails for the domains?

Comment: Have a look at this topic.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976712/using-mx-records-to-validate-email-addresses

Comment: Even if it could be done, it'd be pointless. What if e-mail exists but belongs to someone else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Generate a token
2. Store that token against the email address in a database
3. Send an email to that address with a URL that includes the token and a hash of the email address

If someone visits that URL, then the address exists.

SMTP provides a mechanism to ask if a server hosts a particular address, but it is almost always disabled as it is a favourite tool of spammers.

Comment: Correct. There's no other way. Seriously. E-mail is not different from snail mail.

Comment: its mean we must send email to given address there's no alternate way